# Sending email in java spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-mail

I am having trouble sending an email in my spring webapp. I am using spring mvc.

I have mail configuration class:

```
@Configuration
class MailConfig {

     @Bean(name="mailSender")
    public MailSender javaMailService() {
        JavaMailSenderImpl javaMailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
        javaMailSender.setHost("smtp.gmail.com");
        javaMailSender.setPort(587);
        javaMailSender.setProtocol("smtp");
        javaMailSender.setUsername("email@gmail.com");
        javaMailSender.setPassword("password");
        Properties mailProperties = new Properties();
        mailProperties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        mailProperties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "starttls");
        mailProperties.put("mail.smtp.debug", "true");
        javaMailSender.setJavaMailProperties(mailProperties);
        return javaMailSender;
    }

}
```

And in controller I have autowired  instance of `mailSender` and I send emails like this:

```
@Autowired
MailSender mailSender;

@RequestMapping(path="emailTest", method = {RequestMethod.GET})
    public void emailTest(){

        SimpleMailMessage smm = new SimpleMailMessage();

        smm.setFrom("email@gmail.com");
        smm.setTo("email@gmail.com");
        smm.setSubject("title");
        smm.setText("text");

        mailSender.send(smm);

    }
```

And when I try to send I get

```
HTTP Status 500 - Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/mail/util/MessageRemovedIOException
```

Comment: I suppose adding [javax.mail](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.mail/javax.mail/1.6.0) dependency will solve your issue.

Comment: @SergeyProkofiev Thanks, it did, but now I get `SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. a69sm529238wme.29 - gsmtp`

Answer (score 2):

You should also have `mail.jar` on the classpath. You can find reference [solution here](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-sun-mail-util-messageremovedioexception/).

Comment: Thanks, that helped, but now I get this: `SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. a69sm529238wme.29 - gsmtp`

Comment: See the [JavaMail FAQ](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#starttls).

Answer (score 1):

Please verify, have you added `mail.jar`.